# PDO Class and Personal Class, how to set a method more than once

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I'm writing a Class for PHP PDO so that I can shorter the prepare and execute methods.

Instead of having to write a prepare and bind every time:

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:db.sdb');
$prep = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO animals (animal_type, animal_name) VALUES (:animal_type, :animal_name)");
$data_to_set = array(':animal_type' => 'Cow', ':animal_name' => 'Carolina');
$prep->execute($data_to_set);
```

In this case animal_type and animal_name get repeated so I'm creating a Class that cuts this out:

```
class QuickPDO{

    public $fields, $values, $args;

    public function __construct($args){

        foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
            $this->fields .= substr($key, 1).', ';
            $this->values .= $key.", ";
        }
        $this->values= substr($this->values, 0, -2);
        $this->fields = substr($this->fields, 0, -2);
        $this->args = $args;

    }

    public function insert($table){
        $returning_query = "INSERT INTO $table ($this->fields) VALUES ($this->values)";
        return $returning_query;
    }

}
```

So this gets easier and becomes:

```
$myPDO = new QuickPDO([':animal_type' => 'Cow', ':animal_name' => 'Carolina']);
$prep = $db->prepare($myPDO->insert('animals'));
$prep->execute($myPDO->args);
```

Up to here, no problem. But this way I can only do one prepare for each QuickPDO Object, which is not very convenient, so I thought to change the __construct into a function "set":

```
public function set($args){

    foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
        $this->fields .= substr($key, 1).', ';
        $this->values .= $key.", ";
    }
    $this->values= substr($this->values, 0, -2);
    $this->fields = substr($this->fields, 0, -2);
    $this->args = $args;

}
```

And call it this way:

```
$myPDO = new QuickPDO();
$myPDO->set([':animal_type' => 'Cow', ':animal_name' => 'Carolina']);   
$prep = $db->prepare($myPDO->insert('animals'));
$prep->execute($myPDO->args);
```

The problem comes when I try to do a new set() to $myPDO. I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Sounds too much trouble just to add a row with 2 columns to a table.

Comment: @silkfire what do you mean? I don't get it, this is a test with 2 columns but can be expanded. As I wrote "I'm writing a class" and this is for future use. Why the -1?

Comment: "Instead of having to write a prepare and bind everytime". What's so bothersome with that? You only prepare once, then you execute multiple times. This can be sped up with a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved

```
$myPDO->set([':animal_type' => 'Like', ':animal_name' => 'This']);
$prep = $db->prepare($myPDO->insert('animals'));
$prep->execute($myPDO->args);
$myPDO->set([':animal_type' => 'Works', ':animal_name' => 'Fine']);
$prep->execute($myPDO->args);
```

The sequence is important...